# Return null in LinkedList is basically return null

Tags: java

I have three classes Customer, Store and items

I am using 'LinkedList' to move around classes.

Item Class

```
public class Item {
    public Item(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + code;
    }

}
```

Store class

```
    public class Store {
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();

    public Store(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void addItem(String code, String name){
          items.add(new Item(this, code, name);
       }

    public LinkedList<Item> viewItem(){
           for(int j = 0 ; j < items.size(); j++)
               System.out.println(items.get(j))
           return null; // I though return null you just return nothing. But it literally return null;
       }
}
```

Customer

```
   public class Customer {
    private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();

    public Customer() {
        stores.add(new Store("Game", "1"));
        stores.add(new Store("Grocery", "2"));

        stores.get(0).addItem("001A", "GTA");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

        stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Customer().view();
    }

    public void view() {
        System.out.println(stores.get(0).viewItem());
    }

}
```

I only want to return

```
GTA : 001A
GODS OF WARS : 001B
THE LAST OF US: 001C
```

But instead it also returning "null" How can I eliminate it.

I tried use just Activity but it only return one.

I cannot remove LinkedList because it gotta return a series of video games.

Can someone explain to me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `Customer.view`, you are printing out the result of the function `Store.viewItem`. And because your `viewItem` function returns `null`, that print statement is going to print `null`.

Simply remove the print statement and you should get what you're looking for:

```
public void view(){
    stores.get(0).viewItem();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this

```java
public LinkedList<Item> viewItem() {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < items.size(); j++)
       System.out.println(items.get(i))
    return null; 
}
```

more precisely this `System.out.println(items.get(i))` what is `i` ? your variable loop is called `j`

Then `return null` explicitly is a bad practice.

Better approach :

```java
 public LinkedList<Item> items() {
    return new LinkedList(items); 
 }
```

then

```
 public void view() {
    stores.get(0).items().forEach(System.out::println);
 }
```